# field is not created or edited

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

Field is not created or edited in views Create and Edit (C# MVC4 CodeFirst).
The rest of the field with the data types string or integer created and edited properly and correctly.

In Model **Requirement**:

```
...

    public int RequirementId { get; set; }

    //[StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 500)]
    public string Definition { get; set; }
    public string Rationale { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Users CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Responsible { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Users> InterestedPersons { get; set; }

    public string CurentVersion { get; set; }
    public StateEnum State { get; set; }
    public PriorityEnum Priority { get; set; }
    public StabilityEnum Stability { get; set; }
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    public virtual BusinessRule Source { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestCase> TestCase { get; set; }

    public string UserPart { get; set; }


...
```

Controller **RequirementController** (in method Create):

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        RequirementViewModel reqVM = new RequirementViewModel();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<RequirementViewModel, Requirement>();
        reqVM.UserList = new SelectList(db.Users, "UsersId", "Surname");
        reqVM.BusinessRuleList = new SelectList(db.BusinessRule, "BusinessRuleId", "Definition");
        reqVM.TestCaseList = new SelectList(db.TestCase, "TestCaseId", "Title");
        Requirement requirement = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<RequirementViewModel, Requirement>(reqVM);

        return View();
    }

        //
        // POST: /Requirement/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Requirement requirement)
        {
             try
            {
                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<RequirementViewModel, Requirement>();
                reqVM.UserList = new SelectList(db.Users, "UsersId", "Surname");
                reqVM.BusinessRuleList = new SelectList(db.BusinessRule, "BusinessRuleId", "Definition");
                reqVM.TestCaseList = new SelectList(db.TestCase, "TestCaseId", "Title");

                Requirement requirement = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<RequirementViewModel, Requirement>(reqVM);

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Requirement.Add(requirement);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index"); //, new { id = requirement.InterestedPersons }
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }

            return View();
}
```

View **Create**:

```
    ...

  @model OpenSoft.AgileAnalytics.EF.Models.Requirement 
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
   }

<h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Requirement</legend>
        @*@Html.EditorForModel()*@

        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Definition)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Definition)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Definition)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rationale)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rationale)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rationale)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CreatedBy, Model.UserList, "-Select-") //error
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Responsible)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Responsible, Model.UserList, "-Select-") //error
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Responsible)
    </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InterestedPersons)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.InterestedPersons, Model.UserList) //error
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InterestedPersons)
        </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurentVersion)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurentVersion)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurentVersion)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPart)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPart)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPart)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.EnumDropDownList(model => model.StateEnum)*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(OpenSoft.AgileAnalytics.EF.Models.StateEnum))))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)            
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Priority, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(OpenSoft.AgileAnalytics.EF.Models.PriorityEnum))))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Priority)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stability)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Stability, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(OpenSoft.AgileAnalytics.EF.Models.StabilityEnum))))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Stability)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, new  SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(OpenSoft.AgileAnalytics.EF.Models.TypeEnum))))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Source)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("BusinessRuleId", "-Select-")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Source)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestCase)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("TestCaseId", "-Select-")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestCase)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
  }

   <div>
      @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
   </div>

   @section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }

    ...
```

In the drop-down lists the elements of the right.
Help please with the work with these fields model:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties `CreatedBy`, `Responsible` and `InterestedPersons` are complex objects. A `<select>` only posts back a single value (or array of values in the case of `multiple`). In addition the name of your dropdowns are all `UsersId` but your model does not contain a property named `UsersId` so nothing is bound.

Create a view model to represent the data you want to edit.

```
public class RequirementVM
{
  public int RequirementId { get; set; }
  public string Definition { get; set; }
  .... // other properties of Requirement that you want to edit

  [Required]
  [Display(Name="Created by")]
  public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int? Responsible { get; set; }

  public int[] InterestedPersons { get; set; }

  public SelectList UserList { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  RequirementVM model = new MyViewModel();
  model.UserList = new SelectList(db.Users, "UsersId", "Surname");
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RequirementVM model)
{
  ...
}
```

View

```
@model RequirementVM
....
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Definition)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Definition)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Definition)

... other properties of RequirementVM to edit

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreatedBy)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CreatedBy, Model.UserList, "-Select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CreatedBy)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Responsible)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Responsible, Model.UserList, "-Select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Responsible)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.InterestedPersons)
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.InterestedPersons, Model.UserList)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InterestedPersons)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not do as you suggest. After all, it turns out that I will have a single view of these three fields, and I need them to be together with other fields from another model on the same page.

Comment: I don't know what you other properties are - you did not post them in your question. The view model obviously needs to include those other properties as well!

Comment: I added a more detailed code, please help to understand

Comment: @ТатьянаДрузенко, I have updated my answer to add a few extra properties from your data model. You just need to include all the properties that you want to edit in `RequirementVM` and base you view on `RequirementVM` (not `Requirement`). Note `Source` and `TestCase` need to be similar to what I have shown for `CreatedBy` and `InterestedPersons` (they are also complex objects). When this posts back to `public ActionResult Create(RequirementVM model)`, `model.CreatedBy` will contain the ID of the selected user and `model.InterestedPersons` will contain an array of selected user ID's

Comment: ,Thank you very much for your help! I will try to do what you said.

Comment: I did as you wrote, but when you create an error on the page: "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator." . And at this time in the VisualStudio an error: "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll".

Comment: I understand that View Create that was previously not needed and it is necessary to replace the files that you have written to me? 
And now if I need a model Requirement instead now RequirementVM?

Comment: That an unrelated error (to do with EF) but I suspect that the issue is that the view model you return to the post action is `RequirementVM` (not the data model `Requirement`) so you cant save the view model to the database. You need to get the original `Requirement` and map the properties from the view model to the data model then save that.

Comment: I need to change the method Create in the controller requirement?

Comment: If you mean in the POST method, then yes.

Comment: I did as you advised. But I got an error while creating a new requirement:
"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_2vxbpywv.dll but was not handled in user code".
The error points to a string: "@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CreatedBy, Model.UserList, "-Select-")" in view Create. Model = null: Simple field shall be made normally, and all the complex field are NULL :((

Comment: In your POST method, if you return the view then you also need to reassign the `SelectList` values - `model.UserList = new SelectList(db.Users, "UsersId", "Surname");` as you did in the GET method.

Comment: This is my POST method Create: 
try{          
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<RequirementViewModel, Requirement>();
reqVM.UserList = new SelectList(db.Users, "UsersId", "Surname");
reqVM.BusinessRuleList = new SelectList(db.BusinessRule, "BusinessRuleId", "Definition");
reqVM.TestCaseList = new SelectList(db.TestCase, "TestCaseId", "Title");
Requirement requirement = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<RequirementViewModel, Requirement>(reqVM);
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.Requirement.Add(requirement);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");}
}
}
catch (DataException ex)
{...
}
return View();

Comment: I added my answer and add code of new method Create(POST)

Comment: Its late. I'll look in the morning, but you cant map RequirementViewModel directly to Requirement without setting additional parameters

Comment: Hello, you can see how I predelala method Create (POST)? Why go wrong?

Comment: Your not doing you mapping correctly. If when you post back, the properties of `RequirementVM` are correctly populated, then I have answered this question correctly. Creating a `Requirement` from `RequirementVM` is a different issue. You should do some research and if you cant solve the problem, then you need to ask a new question (that's how SO works). [These articles](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-getting-started/) might be a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for such a good article